# Random int infinite loop

Tags: python, random, infinite-loop

This function dosen't stop after choosing one integer, it keeps doing that in an infinite loop. Can anyone tell me why, or how can I repair this issue?

```
def wGen():
    top = len(Repo.words)
    randInt = random.randint(0,len(Repo.words))
    print randInt, top
```

It produces this output: (1037 is the number of elements in the database)

```
...
214 1037
731 1037
46 1037
490 1037
447 1037
103 1037
342 1037
547 1037
565 1037
90 1037
...
```

There you go i call the function with this 'menu alike function'

```
def gameMenu():
"""Game Menu"""

gameMenuPrint()

def m():
    inp = raw_input('enter option: ')
    while inp != 'q':
        if inp == 'play' or inp =='1': GameC.wGen()
        elif inp == 'help' or inp =='2': pass
        elif inp == 'back' or inp =='0': mainMenu()
        else:
            print 'wrong input!'
            inp = raw_input('enter valid a option!: ')
m()
```

Comment: Can you show the calling code?

Comment: The function you give works for me. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I edited  my post with the code, which calls the function. is it that what you mean?

Comment: Look at your code! If you type 'play' it goes back to the top of the `while` loop and doesn't ask for new input...

Answer (score 4):

This part is the problem:

```
def m():
    inp = raw_input('enter option: ')
    while inp != 'q':
        if inp == 'play' or inp =='1': GameC.wGen()
        elif inp == 'help' or inp =='2': pass
        elif inp == 'back' or inp =='0': mainMenu()
        else:
            print 'wrong input!'
            inp = raw_input('enter valid a option!: ')
```

You ask for `raw_input` before entering the loop. Once you enter the loop, you never ask for input again. Change it to this:

```
def m():
    inp = raw_input('enter option: ')
    while inp != 'q':
        if inp == 'play' or inp =='1': GameC.wGen()
        elif inp == 'help' or inp =='2': pass
        elif inp == 'back' or inp =='0': mainMenu()
        else:
            print 'wrong input!'
        inp = raw_input('enter option: ')
```

Though I'd actually prefer this:

```
def m():
    while True:
        inp = raw_input('enter option: ')
        if inp == 'q': break
        elif inp == 'play' or inp =='1': GameC.wGen()
        elif inp == 'help' or inp =='2': pass
        elif inp == 'back' or inp =='0': mainMenu()
        else:
            print 'wrong input!'
```

Comment: well idont call for m() i cal for gameMenu()... look again

Comment: @BogdanMaier what? Did you understand my answer or not?

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out after wGen() i forgot to return to the emnu and that  looped for ever thank you, you pointed it out right:) thanks

Answer (score 0):

The while condition will always be true unless they enter 'q' in the first raw_input. You never get a new value for inp. Add another raw_input into your while loop.